# JSF EL String comparison

Tags: string, jsf, el

What is wrong in the EL used for style attribute of `inputText`:

I can correctly see the title string of `inputText` in browser when it is rendered, but when I do some string comparison for its value it is always returning 155:

```
<h:inputText
                                        id="filterTextInput" rendered="#{myBean.inputTypeText}"
                                        value="#{myBean.value}" title="#{myBean.label}"
                                        styleClass="textField floatL clearL" 
                                    style="width:#{myBean.label.contains('Location Full Name') ? '170' :
                                            myBean.label.contains('Address Prefix') ? '93' :
                                            myBean.label.contains('Address #') ? '70' :
                                            myBean.label.contains('Address Suffix') ? '94' :                
                                            myBean.label.contains('Street Name') ? '171' :              
                                            myBean.label.contains('Customer Full Name') ? '80' :
                                            myBean.label.contains('City') ? '132' :
                                            myBean.label.contains('Zip') ? '50' :
                                            myBean.label.contains('Building CLLI') ? '120' :
                                            myBean.label.contains('Location ID') ? '120' : '155'}px">
                                            <f:validator validatorId="locationInputValidator" />
                                            <f:attribute name="maxLength" value="#{myBean.colspan}" />
</h:inputText>
```

Comment: what was the value of `myBean.label` ?

Comment: the same value which i am using for comparison inside contains ('Address Prefix'). I am able to see the value on input text as title, but the el is returning only 155 for all fields. This inputText is used inside a <ui:repeat value="#{fieldsRow}" var="myBean">

Comment: may be try this way `#{myBean.label.contains('Location Full Name') == 'true' ? : }`

Comment: still getting same result for style : width: 155px;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using parentheses solved the problem :

```
<h:inputText

         id="filterTextInput" rendered="#{myBean.inputTypeText}"
                                            value="#{myBean.value}" title="#{myBean.label}"
                                            styleClass="textField floatL clearL" 
                                            style="width:#{myBean.label.contains('Location Full Name') ? '170' :
                                            (myBean.label.contains('Address Prefix') ? '93' :
                                            (myBean.label.contains('Address #') ? '70' :
                                            (myBean.label.contains('Address Suffix') ? '94' :                                       
                                            (myBean.label.contains('Street Name') ? '171' :                                     
                                            (myBean.label.contains('Customer Full Name') ? '80' :
                                            (myBean.label.contains('City') ? '132' :
                                            (myBean.label.contains('Zip') ? '50' :
                                            (myBean.label.contains('Building CLLI') ? '120' :
                                            (myBean.label.contains('Location ID') ? '120' : '155')))))))))}px">
                                            <f:validator validatorId="locationInputValidator" />
                                            <f:attribute name="maxLength" value="#{myBean.colspan}" />
</h:inputText>
```

now, i am getting appropriate value of width in style property and inputText is sized accordingly.